# Letters with accents input problem on the jar (with cmd / powershell) but not on the IDE

Tags: java, cmd, jar, non-ascii-characters

I was working on one of my projects and I realise that when I built it, the program's behaviour was not the same in cmd/powershell than in the IDE console.

The problem is about the letters with accents. For example :

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String test = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

This code in the IDE do this :
my input : aéééa
IDE output (the print) : aéééa

BUT, when I build the jar, execute it and type exactly the same input I got this output
: a___a  (because starkoverflow doesn't allow several spaces that follow each other I wrote "_" but it is space, so in reality éé is two space characters).

So as you can see, it replace the "é" by space.
Therefore I tried a lot of character like &"'()-è_çàê and only the letters with accents don't work (éèàê). I remind you that everything works well in the IDE console.

Trying to solve this problem I tested thing like that :

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But still doesn't work on the built jar...

Consequently, I decided to do the same thing in Python to find out if the problem was with my OS or cmd/powershell.

```py
print('input: ')
x = input()
print('-> ' + x)
```

It turns out that this code works perfectly, when I input : aéééa, I got aéééa in the cmd.

Can someone have an explanation for this ?? I am lost and I don't know how to do to fix this...

Answer (score 1):

Using JDK17+ I assume?

> `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Right idea, wrong direction. Java defaults to UTF_8 for everything since JDK17 or so, and your OS is *not* UTF_8. You want your OS-native encoding.

Java is oriented towards platform independent, reliable (as in, runs the same way on all platforms) code. In contrast to e.g. python which is much more oriented towards command line scripty stuff (so, unlock OS-specific takes and systems, which in tradeoff means it's less reliable, in the sense that python code runs differently on different platforms).

Charset default behaviour is part of that. There are advantages and disadvantages to defaulting everything to UTF-8, and there are advantages and disadvantages to defaulting to OS-native default.

See [this CSR](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8266075) for more info.

You want this somewhat convoluted mess:

```java
Charset nativeCharset = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("native.encoding", Charset.defaultCharset().name()));

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, nativeCharset);
```

Remind me to ask the java team to make this less shit. `Charset.nativeEncoding()` would be nice.

---

So why *does* it work inside your IDE? Simple, because that IDE's mini-console window thing *is* configured in UTF-8 even if your OS is not.

Comment: I believe you meant [Charset.defaultCharset()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()), not defaultEncoding().

Comment: Thanks for the intresting answer, i added the code but with the Charset.defaultCharset() and not the defaultEncoding() because it wasn't avaible, but now i have strange character in the IDE console x)

Comment: Yes, I did, @VGR. Well spotted. I shall edit the answer.

Comment: @Numix IDEs have their own little mini-console thing going on. It sounds like your IDE is broken: It uses UTF_8 (possibly because, and that was really silly of them, they are trying to work around this problem), but doesn't fix the "native.encoding" property. There is nothing you can do about this, other than file bug reports, and write work-around code, for example by having a command line flag or -D option that forces a different charset, and then edit your IDE 'run the app inside the IDE' definition set that flag with UTF_8.

Comment: I see, but i don't know why the program still doesn't work, same problem in cmd (space) :(

Comment: ```byte[] a = "aéééa".getBytes();
java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(i -> a[i]).forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%02X ", 0xFF & i));```  prints what?

Comment: On IDE : 61 C3 A9 C3 A9 C3 A9 61
On CMD : 61 E9 E9 E9 61

Comment: Do you know what that tells you?

Comment: Unicode character and UTF8 ones, but don't really understand what's going on and how to fix it lol

Comment: No - it tells you that your system (via cmd.exe) is *not* Unicode, but your IDE has been fixed up to be so. Yes, we kind of already knew that but it's good to get these things clear. Now, let me check - the  problem is that your IDE is *still* outputting blanks where you're entering accented Es?

Comment: No, all is good in my IDE, but not in my cmd with the built jar. And my cmd understands letters with accents (like i show with the python script in my post)

Comment: So you can type in an E acute *directly* into cmd.exe? Oh and can you say what `java -version` prints in cmd?

Comment: java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS

Comment: Ok but of course since you don't run real code in an IDE, you should have altered your code to that given in the answer . Did you do that? Oh and you didn't answer the question about typing

Comment: @Numix when compiling, `javac -encoding UTF-8`.